# Xelement adds element value to itself twice

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, linq

In my code i iterate through an xelement and have it return the value of each node within that element e.g.

```
foreach(XElement n in XDocument.Descedants("element_name)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Searching: " n.Value);
 }
```

My problem is the both `<Directory>` elements are returned in the string

```
Searching: C:\Users\215358\OneDrive\MusicC:\Users\215358\Dropbox\Music
```

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Directories>
  <Directory>C:\Users\215358\OneDrive\Music</Directory>
  <Directory>C:\Users\215358\Dropbox\Music</Directory>
</Directories>
```

I expect it to output the second line element in `<Directory>` like this:

```
C:\Users\215358\Dropbox\Music
```

Why  is this happening?

Comment: How does your `xml` looks like? also explain what output expected.

Comment: What is your search criteria? or you just want to take the last element?

Comment: I want to search through all the elements one at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XElement.Value gets the [concatenated text contents of an element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx).  This includes the text of child elements which is not always very helpful.  If you just want the text from the current element, you can find the text node in its child nodes.

```
foreach(XElement n in XDocument.Descedants("Directory"))
{
    var text = n.Nodes().Where (x => x is XText).Cast<XText>().FirstOrDefault ();
    if(text!=null){
        Console.WriteLine("Searching: " + text.Value);
    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("No text node found");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but It only outputs the first Directory in the file. I want it to give me all the directories one after the other.. 

EDIT: I read it wrong. It works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to iterate through each entry and search element value, you could do something like this.

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("Directory"))
{
     if((string)element.Value == "searchstring")
     {
          // your logic
     }  
}
```

In case if you are looking for second element in the `xml`, you could apply `Skip` extension to skip specified count of elements.

```
var secondelement = doc.Descendants("Directory").Skip(1); // Skip first element;
```

or if you are looking for last element, you could take `Last` or `LastOrDefault` extension.

```
var lastelement = doc.Descendants("Directory").LastOrDefault();
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BNtgqR).